# Why does this Ruby code return the object id as well as the method I am calling?

Tags: ruby

I am currently doing pragmatic studios course and this is some code I wrote for one of the exercises. When I run the code I get an object id in addition to the method I intended to call. The exercise creates a game where you can increase or decrease a players health using a blam or w00t method.

```
    class Player ##creates a player class
attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :health
def initialize fname, lname, health=100
 @fname, @lname, @health = fname.capitalize, lname.capitalize, health
end

def to_s
   #defines the method to introduce a new player
   #replaces the default to_s method 
  puts "I'm #{@fname} with a health of #{@health}."
end

def blam #the method for a player to get blammed?
  @health -= 10
  puts "#{@fname} got blammed!"
end
def w00t #the method for a player getting wooted
  @health += 15
  puts "#{@fname} got w00ted"
end
end
larry = Player.new("larry","fitzgerald",60)
curly = Player.new("curly","lou",125)
moe = Player.new("moe","blow")
shemp = Player.new("shemp","",90)

puts larry
puts larry.blam
puts larry
puts larry.w00t
puts larry
```

My output looks like this:

```
I'm Larry with a health of 60.
#<Player:0x10e96d6d8>
Larry got blammed!
nil
I'm Larry with a health of 50.
#<Player:0x10e96d6d8>
Larry got w00ted
nil
I'm Larry with a health of 65.
#<Player:0x10e96d6d8>
```

I can't figure out why the object ids (or nil) is printed to the console when I run the code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your functions should be returning strings, but they are actually returning the result of `puts "something"`

do this instead:

```
def w00t
 @health += 15
 "#{@fname} got w00ted"
end
```

Then when you do `puts obj.w00t`, it will perform the action, and return the string.

Comment: @JeffBaird happy to help. In a few minutes you should be able to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Every method in Ruby returns a value so the #blam method does return something. In this case it is the value of the last expression: the result of calling puts, which is nil.  So when you `puts larry.blam` you are puts-ing the return of the last statement, puts, and thus nil.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove some `puts`. Your methods prints everything on stdout, and you prints their result.